# Mixins and Jackson annotations

Tags: java, jackson, mixins

We currently have some mixins for our data objects in order to keep annotations out of the data objects.  So for example

```
public class SomeDataObj {
    private int a;

    public int getA() { return this.a; }

    public void setA(final int a) { this.a = a; }
}

public interface SomeDataObjMixin {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "A")
    int getA();

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "A")
    void setA(int a);
}
```

Then in our object mapper class we have

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class OurXmlMapper extends XmlMapper {


    public OurXmlMapper(final ConfigurableCaseStrategy caseStrategy) {
        setPropertyNamingStrategy(caseStrategy);
        setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

        //yadda yadda

        addMixin(SomeDataObj.class, SomeDataObjMixin.class);

        // etc etc

}
```

However, for various reasons I'd like to add a new annotation to the private field in the data object, not the getter or setter.  Is there a way to accomplish this through a mixin to maintain that separation?  I tried creating a basic class as a mixin (not an interface) and added the private field with the 
 new annotation to that.  This didn't accomplish what I was looking for.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using Concrete class as mixin working.

```
// ******************* Item class *******************
public class Item {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

// ******************* ItemMixIn class *******************
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "item-class")
public class ItemMixIn {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "firstName")
    private String name;

}

// ******************* test method *******************
public void test() throws Exception {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    mapper.addMixIn(Item.class, ItemMixIn.class);

    Item item = new Item();
    item.setName("hemant");

    String res = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(item);
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

Output:

```
<item-class>
  <firstName>hemant</firstName>
</item-class>
```

I have jackson version **2.9.5**.

Comment: Thanks.  I've realised something since asking which renders my questions useless.